# Making list of figures captions wrap before the numbering

Tags: table-of-contents

My dissertation style manual has this guidance that in the list of figures a long caption should wrap before the page numbering so they do not collide as shown below:

[image: See how the lines wrap earlier than numbering?]

But so far I have a list of figures where my captions wrap to the next line pretty much in the normal place:

[image]

Is there a simple way to force this wrapping to happen at some arbitrary point before the end of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use tocloft package, the @tocrmarg length controls this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{15.55em} % versus 2.55em
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures


\begin{figure}
\caption{short text}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if OP doesn't use `tocloft`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Then the OP should add tocloft package!

Comment: I have to disagree :-) Never have I used `tocloft` in my documents, and all of them turned out okay without it.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You are free not to use my answer. I don't see the point of this discussion. Either the OP will like it or accept one of the other answers which might use whatever package you seems to prefer over tocloft.

Comment: There are other packages that manipulate these lists, so if OP already loads one of them it might not be that easy to switch. I just think you should wait to post an answer that will solve the issue, not just a guess.

Comment: I really appreciate the fast answer, but that package must have conflicted with others that I am using since it threw a bunch of errors and completely changed the layout of the rest of the table of contents, which i liked the way it was. Thanks again.

Comment: @remington Unfortunaly there is no MWE in your question, so we don't know which class and packages regarding the TOC do you load. But the suggested change of `\@tocrmarg` doesn't need package `tocloft`.  So it should work without this package, too.

Comment: @esdd oh thank you! that worked great without tocloft package.